# Keep getting ~N/A

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a simple 2 column array and all I want to do is use Vlookup to find the matching value in Column 1 and return the value out of column 2. I keep getting #N/A which implies that my "answer" isn't there. I thought I had done everything correctly, but I can't seem to find the answer despite reading MANY #N/A questions. This is my code:-

```vb
Dim y as Variant
Dim Misc_Pay(1 to 16,1 to 2 ) as Variant.
' Populate the Misc_Pay array
Misc_Pay(1,2) = "Cancer,3"
Misc_Pay(2,2) = "Clerical,Last of Month"
Misc_Pay(3,2) = "Halifax,14"
Misc_Pay(4,2) = "Reward,1"
'and so on down to 
Misc_Pay(16,2) = "Last Line,End of File"
'My Vlook up code is:-
y = (Application.Vlookup("Reward",Misc_Pay,2,False)
```

I've then been printing "y" out so I can see what value it is picking up, except it doesn't appear to be picking anything up, but e.g. "Reward" is patently there.

If I can get this line to work then the full line code will be:-

```
If(iserror(Application.Vlookup("Reward,Misc_Bay,2,False) then 'do something' Else 'do something else'
```

Comment: Do you want me to try again?Ah, I see what you mean. Sorry all!!!

Answer (score 0):

To start, the code you posted won't compile, due to the period at the end on line 2, and the extra `(` on the last line.

If you're trying to do a lookup in a 2D array, you need to set values for both the key and lookup columns (in this case, columns 1 and 2 respectively). Currently, you're just assigning the entire string with the comma to the second column, so there's nothing to look up in the first column.

I think what you want is this:

```
Dim y As Variant
Dim Misc_Pay(1 To 16, 1 To 2) As Variant

Misc_Pay(1, 1) = "Cancer"
Misc_Pay(1, 2) = "3"

Misc_Pay(2, 1) = "Clerical"
Misc_Pay(2, 2) = "Last of Month"

Misc_Pay(3, 1) = "Halifax"
Misc_Pay(3, 2) = "14"

Misc_Pay(4, 1) = "Reward"
Misc_Pay(4, 2) = "1"

Misc_Pay(16, 1) = "Last Line"
Misc_Pay(16, 2) = "End of File"

y = Application.VLookup("Reward", Misc_Pay, 2, False)
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, I'm learning VBA one problem at a time, and I am most grateful for both your help, personally, and those of the other contributors to Stackoverflow. Not sure what us "newbies" would do without you. Thanks again. Like they say "It's simple when you know how!!"